# Select item in custom QComboBox not working

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qcombobox

I have a custom QComboBox with a TreeView to split child item in different sections, the parent items are not selectable. When the user triggers it works fine, but when i try to automatically select one of the item, it seems like my comboBox only sees the parent items. Maybe someone could help.

Here is my custom comboBox, (`selectChildItem` will only select a parent item, `findText` of a childItem will return -1).
The index of the `currentIndexChanged` event when the user triggers and select a child item is 0

```
class CustomComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomComboBox, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.view.setHeaderHidden(True)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setView(self.view)

    def addUserItems(self, header, items):
        userItem = QtGui.QStandardItem(header)
        userItem.setSelectable(False)
        for item in sorted(items):
            childItem = QtGui.QStandardItem(item)
            userItem.appendRow(childItem)
        self.model.appendRow(userItem)

        self.view.expandAll()
        self.view.setItemsExpandable(False)

    # This does not select the child item
    def selectChildItem(self, itemText):
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            headerItem = self.model.item(row)
            for col in range(headerItem.rowCount()):
                childItem = headerItem.child(col)
                if childItem.text() == itemText:
                    self.view.selectionMode()
                    index = self.model.indexFromItem(childItem)
                    self.setCurrentIndex(index.row())
```

Comment: You need to change the root index of the combo (and restore that of the view). `setCurrentIndex()` only sets the *row index* (an integer) based on the combo root index. You should also break/return when the match has been found.

Comment: Note that based on your question and its code, it seems like you just want to *separate* items in sections, so a tree model is probably unnecessary: instead, create "headers" as standard items, and make them *disabled* (`item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~(Qt.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemIsSelectable))`).